# Converting VisDrone annotations to YOLO format using multiprocessing

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, multiprocessing, yolov5

I tried using VisDrone.yaml for the conversion but it takes very long. I tried modifying the yaml but couldn't make it work.

I tried :

```
  def visdrone2yolo_worker(f):

      def convert_box(size, box):
          # Convert VisDrone box to YOLO xywh box
          dw = 1. / size[0]
          dh = 1. / size[1]
          return (box[0] + box[2] / 2) * dw, (box[1] + box[3] / 2) * dh, box[2] * dw, box[3] * dh

      for f in pbar:
          img_size = Image.open((dir / 'images' / f.name).with_suffix('.jpg')).size
          lines = []
          with open(f, 'r') as file:  # read annotation.txt
              for row in [x.split(',') for x in file.read().strip().splitlines()]:
                  if row[4] == '0':  # VisDrone 'ignored regions' class 0
                      continue
                  cls = int(row[5]) - 1
                  box = convert_box(img_size, tuple(map(int, row[:4])))
                  lines.append(f"{cls} {' '.join(f'{x:.6f}' for x in box)}\n")
                  with open(str(f).replace(os.sep + 'annotations' + os.sep, os.sep + 'labels' + os.sep), 'w') as fl:
                      fl.writelines(lines)  # write label.txt

  def visdrone2yolo(dir):
      (dir / 'labels').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # make labels directory
      pbar = tqdm((dir / 'annotations').glob('*.txt'), desc=f'Converting {dir}')
      with Pool(50) as p:  # create a pool of 50 worker processes
          p.map(visdrone2yolo_worker, pbar)  # apply visdrone2yolo_worker to each file in pbar in parallel

  

  # Convert
  dir = Path(yaml['path'])  # dataset root dir
  for d in  'VisDrone2019-DET-train', 'VisDrone2019-DET-val', 'VisDrone2019-DET-test-dev': 
      visdrone2yolo(dir / d)  # convert VisDrone annotations to YOLO labels
```

I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 478, in _map_async
    chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I tried also without the pbar but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a better way to convert the annotations with a cleaner script, I had been working on this sometime back.

I added the code to convert the annotations as well as the annotations in the YOLO format on my Github [here](https://github.com/adityatandon/VisDrone2YOLO). Feel free to use that for your experiments if you'd like.